# GAS - Adjust table-cell width to content size on a Document's Table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to make the columns that are for amounts to have a width that's adjusted to the size of the largest element. This is for a `Document`'s `Table`.

The result should be like this:

```
|=====================================|
| Item                       | Amount |
| Notebook                   |      1 |
```

I'm wondering whether there's an method that automatically does this (since it's the same behavior that a double click on the column's line divisor do), or if not, how do I calculate it taking into account the width of the inner element.

**Edit:** specified that I'm asking about a `Document` not a `Sheet`.